Windows mdadm storage driver (winMD) debugging
I have been using the windows winMD driver by mark harmstone on github and it was fine for a while. I ended up needing to wipe my computer and reinstall windows. I have a software raid-0 array managed by mdadm. the primary partition on my drive is linux, but i'd like windows to be able to access this software raid-0 array as well, and this functionality is enabled by the winMD driver. On my most recent installation, however, the raid array isn't showing up in disk management or device manager. The winMD driver shows up in Device Manager, and if i check the events tab i see no errors and the most recent event is
Device ROOT\WINMD\0000 was started.
Driver Name: oem13.inf
Class Guid: {71a27cdd-812a-11d0-bec7-08002be2092f}
Service: winmd
Lower Filters:
Upper Filters:
I am new to windows, but the source code for the driver is provided. How can I debug this driver using winDBG (or perhaps someone knows how to just get this version working)?
